Who is this man being noticed by Robert in this scene?
In Braveheart (1995), Robert, the 17th Earl of Bruce, discusses with Craig how Longshanks'
Prima Nocte is a ploy to gain supporters. Robert mentions that his father
advises a neutral stance towards the decree to gain Longshanks' trust:

Craig: A wise plan. And how is your father? We missed him at the council.
Robert: His affairs in France keep him long overdue.

Then Edward looked up and noticed a man in a hood at the top of the
castle watching them as they entered.

Who is this man being noticed by Robert in this scene?

Nothing of use in the draft script; https://imsdb.com/scripts/Braveheart.html

@Valorum Scripts won't make to final cuts sometimes.

Indeed. And this was an early draft by the author of the original book, so quite a lot of the scenes and dialogue have changed by the time the screenplay was finalised.

The hooded figure is Robert the Bruce's father, Robert the Elder. The Bruce later has several conversations with his father, who we again see wearing a hood.

But how can the Elder be there when the Bruce says his father was in France?
The Bruce is lying - because "away in France" sounds better than "hiding away because of leprosy" (although, this is probably not historically correct - then again, it's not the only inaccuracy in the movie).
